# PHP MySQL UPDATE statement succeeds but column is not updated

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

Would appreciate the advise of SO's php/MySQL experts! I am stumped by the following seemingly simple piece of php code.

```
$queryDel = 'UPDATE `cocoon_result` SET `image` = NULL WHERE `id` = "B" AND `post_id` = 183';

$resultDel = mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryDel);
if (!$resultDel)
    $msg .= 'Errormessage: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli) . '<br />';
else if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) == 0)
    $msg .= 'Errormessage: ' . mysqli_error($mysqli) . '<br />';
else
    $msg .= mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) 'row(s) affected. What the ??';
```

The statement succeeds and says that 1 row is affected. However `image` is still the old value. When I entered the same sql statement via phpMyAdmin, the update works. I have tried updating `image` to '' and '123' and the error persists so it's not just when `image` = NULL.

The PRIMARY KEY for table `cocoon_result` is `id` and `post_id`.

Edit: I've transplanted this snippet of code into a new file and it works... it just doesn't work together with the other lines of code in the original file. I've incrementally added back the other parts of the code to this new file and it still works but it's going to be quite crazy for me to add lines of code bit by bit till the original file is reproduced... Plus I'm darn curious as to the reason for this strange behaviour. Anyone?

Comment: Can you reproduce this in an sqlfiddle?

Comment: can't reproduce this in an sqlfiddle I'm afraid...

Comment: Then the problem isn't your query :-)

Comment: Since update is "successful" and 1 row is affected, I don't understand what other reasons there could be for ths error... Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I think your code structire is wrong. Your code should be like this:

```
$queryDel = 'UPDATE `cocoon_result` SET `image` = NULL WHERE `id` = "B" AND `post_id` = 183';

$resultDel = mysqli_query($mysqli, $queryDel);
$affected_rows = mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli);

if ($affected_rows === -1) //if the query has failed, displaying the error
    $msg .= 'Error deleting result list image: ', mysqli_error($mysqli);
else if (mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) == 0) //if the query hasn't returned any rows
    $msg .= 'No rows affected<br />';
else
    $msg .= mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) 'row(s) affected. What the ??';
```

Comment: The value of mysqli_affected_rows($mysqli) here is 1.

Comment: that's not it - $affected_rows = 1